# Python: how to call methods of a running thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I wanted to know if it is somehow possible to call methods defined in a thread from "outside" itself. This is the idea:

```
class ThreadWithCallableMethods(threading.Thread):     
    def callableMethodOne():
        print "This is the first method"

    def callableMethodTwo():
        print "This is the second one"

theThread = ThreadWithCallableMethods()
theThread.start()
theThread.callableMethodOne()
theThread.callableMethodTwo()
```

Comment: What is this thread doing till you call it?

Comment: Any answer is appreciated

Comment: well i thought of it doing nothing until one of the methods is called

Comment: You can have a Manager managing a Queue object. The main thread and the second thread can communicate via the queue. The second thread is in busy wait polling the Queue status until it receives a signal following which it will call its method itself and pass the result back to the main.

Comment: sounds interesting, do you have some sample code?

Comment: Just google "Communication between threads in Python". There are many examples.

Comment: thanks for the quick support, i'll try so :)